# Should a password/username be written in quotes or italics?

Tags: formatting

In a creative writing context, how should computer passwords/usernames appear?

> I opened Todd’s laptop and typed in his password: *Battle_Ship76.*  I went to the settings and changed his password: *Go2Hell.*

> I went to the online portal and put in my information: username *jaylytle20*, password *budapest*.

Would quotes be preferable? Does the punctuation look like it is part of the password?

Answer (score 1):

Although there is no strict convention for passwords and usernames in the English Lexicon, but to emphasize , I suggest use quotes. Italicized texts are hard to read and slow down the reading.

Also refer this here : https://english.stackexchange.com/q/267826/423407